# google sheets use calculation result in formular

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I need help with google sheets.

I got a decent formular, that calculates a time range out of for other cells.

```
=SUM(VALUE($C61)-VALUE($B61))+VALUE($E61)-VALUE($D61)
```

That works pretty well. But, it always displays "00:00" even if the other cells are all empty. I would like to replace the result "00:00" with "", but I do not want to have the calculation doubled in the formula like this:

```
=IF(SUM((VALUE($C61)-VALUE($B61))+VALUE($E61)-VALUE($D61))>0; SUM((VALUE($C61)-VALUE($B61))+VALUE($E61)-VALUE($D61)); "")
```

So, is there a neater way?

Answer (score 1):

You need an intermediate step if you want to neaten it up.

Try using your first formula exactly as described in one column - which could be F61 in this example - then use G61 to perform your IF calculation using F61's contents to either return F61 or "".

```
=IF(F61 > 0; F61; "")
```

Then the magic... hide the F column!

Good luck.